# ESP32 SPI 4bit mode

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm using a ESP32-PICO-V3-02 device and want to send some data to an LCD in 4 bits mode (SCK, CS, D0, D1, D2, D3) to get the fastest speed, but, can't see on the datasheet any information about the pins and how to configure it, only see how to use the SPI in one bit mode. This device uses the SPI0 to communicate with the embedded flash/psram so I think I have to use the VSPI or HSPI.

The SPI Master Driver has a configuration flag called "SPI_TRANS_MODE_QIO" to configure the transaction to 4 bits mode, but, can't find what are the pins to connect the ESP32 to the LCD.

Anyone knows some example code, datasheet, appnote... etc??

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already checked the documentation? https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/spi_master.html Do you have any specific question which is not answered there?

Comment: After read all last night I found it, I'm used to work with STM32 and it's a very different way. I will answer to myself with how to do it for other users.